# Rails + iOS authentication without devise

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a very simple rails app that I rolled my own authentication for, based on the rails tutorial book by Michael Hartl (http://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users). The app is a content management system for an equally simple iOS app. I am aware that devise is very popular, but I really do not think it is necessary for this project. I want to be able to link my iOS app to my rails app, but everywhere I look the only advice I can find is how to do it with devise. All I want to do is have the user be presented with a login screen so they can establish a session and then I can handle all of the permission logic on the rails end of things. Here are a few things to give you an idea of my current authentication scheme:

My session controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  ##
  #Use the email in the nested hash to find the right user
  #Check to make sure that the user authenticates with the given password
  ##
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or root_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token,User.digest(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
    session.delete(:return_to) #not sure if this should really be here or if better way to fix bug
    redirect_and_alert(root_url, "User Successfully Logged Out!",:success)
  end

end
```

Sessions helper:

```
module SessionsHelper
  ##
  #set the remember token for the user
  #make the cookie reflect that token
  #update the users remember token column
  #set the user being passed in as the current user
  ##
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.digest(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  #set the current user
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  #Helper current user method
  def current_user
    remember_token = User.digest(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  #Is the requesting user the current user
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  #Is the user signed in?
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  #Store user request info for friendly forwarding
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  #Store user request info for friendly forwarding
  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
  end

  #Authorization
  def signed_in_user
    store_location
    redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
  end

  def super_user
   redirect_and_alert(root_url,
                      "You are not allowed to do that. Contact the admin for this account.",
                      :error) unless (current_user.role.id == 1)
  end

  def super_user_or_admin
    redirect_and_alert(root_url,
                       "You are not allowed to do that. Contact the admin for this account.",
                       :error) unless (current_user.role.id == 1 || current_user.role.id == 2)
  end

  def is_super_user
    current_user.role.id == 1
  end

  def is_admin
    current_user.role.id == 2
  end

  def is_regular_user
    current_user.role.id == 3
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a token-based system rather than a session-based system.

Create an attribute called authentication token for every user. This token can be generated and assigned during sign-up. The token itself can be generated using simple techniques such as `SecureRandom.hex(n)`, where `n` is the length of the random hex number generated.

After sign-in/sign-up from the app, send the authentication token in the response from the server. You can then have the iOS app send the token along with every subsequent request to the server.

Have the server check the token every time a controller is hit with a request. This can be achieved using the `before_filter`. So a sample controller could look like this:

```
    before_filter :authenticate_user

    def authenticate_user
      # assuming the parameter sent from the app is called auth_token
      auth_token = params[:auth_token]
      user = User.find_by_authentication_token(auth_token)

      if user.nil?
        # what to do if user does not exist
      else
        # what to do if user exists
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically for mobile applications tokens are used instead of sessions. The token is essentially just a string that your Rails app will give each mobile device to verify it has access.

1. Step 1 is to have your mobile app authenticate against the Rails app (this can be through a custom email/password login or through a 3rd party like Facebook).
2. Have your Rails app send a token to the mobile application
3. Store this token in UserDefaults on iOS (help link: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/objective-c-to-swift-guides/nsuserdefaults-swift/)
4. Whenever your app makes a request (or websocket connection, etc.) to the Rails app, send the token (usually as a header).
5. Whenever the iOS app opens, check for the token in UserDefaults. If it is there, then you skip having the user authenticate again.
6. If you want to get really fancy, the Rails app should only accept a token once and issue new-tokens on each request. So your iOS app would send a token on each request and then grab a new one with each response. This is a more secure practice so someone does not grab a token and mess with your Rails app.

This diagram covers the high-level process (it uses FB login for initial authentication, but you can plug yours/an alternate system in instead): http://www.eggie5.com/57-ios-rails-oauth-flow.